# Replace video content within a Blender animation in Other Video Editors

Tags: export, compositing-nodes, lighting

I'm using blender to composite a video within a spinning glass rectangle. Is there anyway I can render out the animation from Blender and replace the video content within AE, but still keep all the glass reflections on the video? it would cut down a lot of render time...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The trick here is rendering out multiple layers so that you can re-combine them later, elsewhere.  In Blender, this utilizes *Scenes*, *Links*, and *Render Passes*.

Create and Animate your spinning card as you would normally.  Then, Create a new scene.  Click the camera and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to bring up the links view.  Link the camera in the scene you just created.  Select the glass object that houses your picture and disable the video.  Link it like you did before to the new scene.  The objects you linked will now exist in both scenes.  *Duplicate* the glass object in the original scene and delete the original glass.  On the duplicate glass, either give it a knockout material or a solid unshaded color you can use to chroma-key, this will depend on the other program.

You now have a scene that consists of the frame and something to key off of when inserting a video, and a separate glass effect you can overlay on top the chroma effect.

This isn't free though:

- With Blender now out of the picture when it comes to the 3d transform of the frame, you will now need to motion-track the frame video you render out if you want the video to not appear to be a window when you composite the video in.  You also lose any dynamic lighting that the video may have once provided.
- You will likely want to render out the Z-Depth of the original scene so you can decide when the video should be occluded correctly.  Most compositors worth their salt will be able to use this info.

If you want to see some of the concepts in motion, I recommend this video that briefly discusses multi-scene renders: https://youtu.be/r7G13NPvXuc.

Comment: Thank you @kirbinator. I came across a plugin that ideally should help me transfer position data from Blender to AE - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XaQCkSzy2YA - but if that doesn't work I will follow your advice.